# JExcel Output Issues

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I'm trying to write out to an Excel Sheet in Java using JExcel.  I successfully write out, however I keep running into the "java.lang.OutOfMemory: Java heap space" error.  From what I've read there are two solutions.

1) Change My Eclipse settings, which I have done and seems to have not made a difference.

My settings are as follows, please let me know if anything looks wrong (Upped Xmx and added the last line):

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

2) Close the workbook to flush output, then reopen and append the next line or group of lines.

This I cannot figure out since I can't find any documentation on it.  When I close my WritableWorkbook (named wwb), I'm not sure how to open it.  I end up writing out one line and then getting a Null error since wwb is closed.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: I ended up switching to SuperCSV, works great.  I had also tried OpenCSV, however it does not escape commas properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to SuperCSV, works great. I had also tried OpenCSV, however it does not escape commas properly